# pyHive error TTransportException: Could not start SASL

Tags: python, hive, kerberos, pyhive

I am trying to connect to remote hive using pyHive.

```
conn = hive.Connection(host='*********', port=10001, database='default', username='********',
                       auth='KERBEROS', kerberos_service_name='hive').cursor()
```

But I always got this error
[image]

**Notes: I already have the kerberos ticket
[image]

Is there something wrong with my configuration ?